# Deletion of document via XPage doesn’t cause deletion of DAOS enabled attachments

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Need your help in the following issue:

I have DAOS enabled XPage application (NSF database). All attachments go to DAOS NLOs when uploaded via XPage. When deleting documents via View (in Notes) – documents are being deleted with its NLO-attachments as expected.

**Issue with deleting documents via XPage:** doing it like

```
dataSource.getDocument().removePermanently(true)
```

deletes document **but doesn’t delete NLO-attachments from DAOS**.

The App database still contains DAOS tickets. Only helps command “load compact -c appDBname.nsf”. Compact causes DBPrune, which cleans that lost (not referenced) NLOs.

Additional information:

- It is Domino 9.0 Server.
- DAOS param  “Defer object deletion for” set to “0”.
- Nightly Daos Prunes also doesn’t clean NLOs (log content: DAOSMGR: DbDelete started -> DAOSMGR: Prune 0 started -> DAOSMGR: DbDelete completed -> DAOS Prune - Deleted 0 objects and completed with error: (0) No error -> DAOSMGR: Prune 0 completed).
- APP DB has “Synchronized” state.
- It’s clean test environment with only one single app, so it is definitely that there are no other applications, which refer to the same NLOs.

Any ideas & advices?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your DAOS catalog in SYNC status? If it needs resync, prune will not have any effect.

Comment: Yes, everything in SYNC status (all commands listed here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.domino.admin85.doc%2FH_DAOS_MANAGER_TELL_COMMANDS_DETAILS.html were checked)

Comment: I would open up a support case with IBM on this matter. Because you are using Domino 9 I assume you have a valid license renewal contact and can create issues with IBM.

Comment: Guys, I found interesting fact: it works! ) But Web (XPages) user has to have access at least "Editor" to DB. If web-user has access level "Author" to DB, and deletes even his document, where he is in Authors field - DAOS NLOs remains, so issue exist. In the APP all users have max "Author" access level. Any ideas, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I can close the issue with the following workaround. As I wrote before, to not have such issue - deletion should be performed by user with at least Editor access level.

So, as workaround: use SSJS and get document via SessionAsSigner.

*I didn't find yet explanation in documentation why it depends on access level...*